# Random variable and Poisson distrubtion

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given that $X$ is a random variable having a Poisson distribution, compute the following:

(a)When $μ=0.5$, $P(X>3)$,

My attempt: $1-e^{-.5}-e^{-.5}-e^{-.5}\cdot0.5-\frac{e^{-.5}\cdot0.5^3}{3}$

(b) When $μ=0.5$, $P(X<1)$,

My attempt: $e^{-.5}+e^{-.5}\cdot0.5$

I am having a little trouble understanding this if someone can help that would be great.

Comment: I guess that $\mu$ is the parameter of your Poisson distribution, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain a little further what you have been trying?
You have to remember that the Poisson distribution is only defined for $x \geq 0$. So, if you want to calculate $P[X>3]$, it is equal to $P[X>3] = 1 - P[X\leq2] = 1 - (P[X=2] + P[X=1] + P[X=0])$. These last three probabilities can be calculated using the density function of $X$, which is $P[X_\mu = k] = \frac{\mu^k}{k!}e^{-\mu}$